# react js useState update the quantity

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react. I have got an issue updating a quantity.

```
const[persons,setPersons] = useState(personLists)
```

if you console.log(persons) it will give output as below. Now I want to
update qty for particular misc index of particular person index .
I have two persons in below array and each person have further two misc array

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "john",
    gender: "m",
    misc: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "xxx",
        qty: 1
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "xxx1",
        qty: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "mary",
    gender: "f",
    misc: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "aaa",
        qty: 1
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "bbb",
        qty: 1
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

Now i want to update qty under misc array for that particular person.I have a function that takes the index of person array and index of misc array as below.

```
const updatePersonMiscQty = (personIndex, miscIndex) => {
  
 setPersons(persons =>

    persons.map((person,key) => {
    const found = person.misc.find(d => key === miscIndex);

    if (found) {
    found.qty += 1;
    }
    return person;
    })



}
```

let say my personIndex is 0 and  miscIndex= is 1
so when usse click the button It should look into first person array, go to second index of misc and update qty.

I am looking for a solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

access the items by indexes and update

```
setPersons(persons => {

    const miscItem = persons[personIndex]?.misc?.[miscIndex]

    if (miscItem ) {
       miscItem.qty += 1;
    }
    return [...persons];
   }
})
```

Comment: This won't cause a render because you are passing the same array

Comment: @TwoHorses added the spread operator to rerender

Comment: This is still mutating `persons` internally, which is not okay.

Comment: Hi @SachilaRanawaka thanks for the answer, however i am getting the error at .misc, and is not compiled once I run npm run dev, can we remove .(dot)

Comment: what's the error

Comment: got an error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')` but I have index 0, the error is here `persons[personIndex]`

Comment: update to this `persons?.[personIndex]?.misc?.[miscIndex]`

Comment: if i console.log(persons[personIndex]?.misc) i get data, but right after that I got an error undefined reading 0

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka, ` console.log('data',persons?.[personIndex]?.misc?.[miscIndex])`, this is not compiled, it shows error in terminal when I run `npm run dev`, and the page shows nothing. I think dot(.) is not supported in my version

Comment: where is this `'data',` coming from. remove i t

Comment: data is just to know data is logged, I have removed data and got the same error.I think dot(.) is not supported in my version. is there a second way to this?

Comment: I am getting unexpected token in this line:  const miscItem = persons[personIndex]?.misc?.[miscIndex]
I am using jsx